# React.js sorting a list in nested components

Tags: reactjs, sorting

How can I sort my shopping list? I have the code as addSort function. Everything looks good to me not sure what im doing wwrong. I can't get it to work. I would like when the user selects the dropdown they can select the option of Alphabetical or list added order. I have the ddropdown working. The function looks right but I can't get it to work.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import classes from './ChoreList.module.css';
// maintain state by importing the usestate

//Possible user actions to events:
//Delete an element
//Mark or unmark as done
// add an element (chore)


  //list of elementswith array of items with unique ids
  //three attribute for each one of the objects 
// Possible user actions to events:
//     delete an element
//     mark or unmark as done (possibly with a checkbox)
//     add an element (chore)
//

const elements = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: "Cucumber",
    done: true
  }
];

function ChoreList(props) {

  const { items, handleDelete, handleCheck, ...my_props } = props;

  // function clickEvent(my_event) {
  //   my_event.preventDefault();
  //   handleDelete(my_event, );
  // }

  return (
    <ul className='myList'>
      {items.map(element => <li id={element.id} key={element.id}>
        <input type='checkbox' 
        checked={element.done} 
        onChange={evt => handleCheck(evt, 
        element.id)}>
        </input> 
      <span className={element.done ? classes.done : classes.notdone }>{element.item}</span> 
      (<a href='null' onClick={(evt) => handleDelete(evt, element.id)}>Remove</a>)</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
} 

function Summary(props) {

  // const { items } = props;
  // items.length  would then refer to the number of item

  return (
    <div className='b-bottom'>{props.items.length} items</div>
  )
}

function AddElement(props) {

  const { addItem, addRef } = props;
  return (
    <div className='holder'>
      <label htmlFor='newitem' className='label-input'>Add Item</label> 
      <input ref={addRef} type='text' id='newitem' className='form-control' />
      <button onClick={addItem} className='button-t'>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}


function sortByItem(props) {

}

function AddSort(props) {

  const [ item, setitem ] = useState(elements);

  const sortItem = (selectEvent) => {
    const options = {
      "a-z": [...item].sort((a, b) => a.item > b.item),
      "z-a": [...item].sort((a, b) => (a < b ? 1 : -1))
    };

    setitem(options[selectEvent.target.value]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropmenu">
      <select onChange={sortItem}>
        <option value="a-z">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="z-a">Order Added</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );

}

function App() {

  const [ item, setitem ] = useState(elements);
  const newChoreRef = useRef();

  function handleDelete(user_event, id) {
      user_event.preventDefault();
      const new_item = item.filter(e => e.id !== id);
      setitem(new_item);
  }

  function handleCheck(user_event, id) {
    console.log("need to change the status of " + id);
    // update state so that done is set to checked (or not)
    console.log(user_event.target.checked);

    // version that uses the ternary operator
    const new_item = item.map(e => (e.id === id) ? 
      {
        id: e.id, 
        item: e.item, 
        done: user_event.target.checked
      } 
      : e);

    // somewhat simpler version
      // const new_item = item.map(e => {
    //   if (e.id == id) {
    //     return {
    //       id: e.id,
    //       item: e.item,
    //       done: user_event.target.checked
    //     }
    //   }
    //   else {
    //     return e;
    //   }
    // });

    // original version
    // const new_item = item.map(e => {
    //   if (e.id == id) {
    //     return {
    //       id: e.id,
    //       item: e.item,
    //       done: user_event.target.checked
    //     }
    //   }
    //   else {
    //     return {
    //       id: e.id,
    //       item: e.item,
    //       done: e.done
    //     }
    //   }
    // });

    setitem(new_item);
  }

  function addItem(evt) {

    const choreDescription = newChoreRef.current.value;
    const newchore = {
      id: item.length + 1,   // it would be better to keep a state that incremented the id
      item: choreDescription,
      done: false
    }
    const new_item = item.concat([newchore]);

    setitem(new_item);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='shoplist-holder'>
        <div className='header-holder'>
          <div className='header-col'>
            <div className='header'><h1>Sams Shopping List</h1></div>
            <Summary items={item}></Summary>
          </div>
          <div className='sub-header'><AddSort items={item}></AddSort></div>
        </div>
      <AddElement addItem={addItem} addRef={newChoreRef}></AddElement>
      <ChoreList items={item} handleDelete={handleDelete} handleCheck={handleCheck}></ChoreList>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of chores is maintained in state inside the `App` component, yet you are attempting to sort the list within the `AddSort` component.

You need to move the `sortItem()` method to the `App` component and pass the method as a prop - just like you do with the `handleDelete` and `handleCheck` handlers.

`<AddSort sortItem={sortItem} items={item}></AddSort>`

You may also find it useful to call `sortItem()` in `useEffect()` to provide an initial sort too.

Comment: Hi, I did what you mentioned. I still can't get it to work https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-zhukovsky-q27jz4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You have made several errors. 1) you have wrapped the `sortItem()` function within another by the same name. Remove the wrapper function. 2) you are not using the event object that is passed into `sortItem()` properly. 3) you need to set the `defaultSelected` attribute of the `select` element. 4) You need to sort on something other than just the object itself. Sort on the `id` property (a.id < b.id). You are on the right track. Good luck.

Comment: you can find all of this [in the documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/components/select#providing-an-initially-selected-option)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is your problem, but it's not about sorting.
Please provide a simple sample when you have issues (it might also help you to realize the issue is not what you think it is)

In any case, this would work fine :

```
const elements = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: "Cucumber"
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    item: "Carrots"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item: "Zucchinis"
  }
];

console.log(elements.sort((a,b) => a.item > b.item ? 1 : -1))

(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
0:(3) {id: 2, item: "Carrots"}
1:(3) {id: 1, item: "Cucumber"}
2:(3) {id: 3, item: "Zucchinis"}
```